# Excel Plotting Data

Tags: excel, powerquery

Starting from an excel table like the following one

[image]

How can i arrive to this kind of table?

[image]

I would like to do it with PowerQuery, not with macros, the table is bigger than this one, of course.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. See "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off...I believe you got your Data numbers and values mixed up between your two table states. For instance, the value 10 is aligned with Data1 in your first table, but with Data2 in your second one. With that said, I think this is what you're after...

Starting with this in a spreadsheet:

[image]

...where the table is named Table1 and has been created with headers, and those headers are titled with a space, Col1, and Col2, do the following.

Load the table (Table1) into PowerQuery: In Excel, click on the Data tab, click on the table, and click on From Table/Range in the ribbon. Make sure My table has headers is checked and click OK. PowerQuery should open and you should see this:

[image]

Now, click on the function icon to the left of the formula bar [image], and type this into the formula bar:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,"""null""",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))
```

...and press enter.

[Alternatively, you could use the GUI to create the above code by selecting oner or more columns (non-numeric, because we're going to replace with a text value), then click the Transform tab and Replace Values, then type null as the Value to Find and "null" as the Replace With and click OK. ...And then edit the resultant code that appears in the formula bar by replacing the list of column names that you had originally selected to Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type").]

You should see this:

[image]

Why did I replace the null values with text? Because if I don't, they'll disappear in the next step, and we want them later. The reason I use `Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")` in the formula, instead of a list of specific column names, is because I don't know how many columns you will have or what they will be called, and this should capture them all.

Now, click on the column with the Data# entries (in the picture above, it's the first column) and then click the Transform tab, and the Unpivot Columns drop-down arrow and Unpivot Other Columns:

[image]

You should see this:

[image]

Now, click on the function icon to the left of the formula bar [image], and type this into the formula bar:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","""null""",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"))
```

...and press enter.

You should see this:

[image]

Here's the complete M code for this:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{" ", type text}, {"Col1", Int64.Type}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,"""null""",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value", {" "}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","""null""",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"))
in
#"Replaced Value1"
```